# Elementary divisors of finite abelian groups. Help to understand

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I am studying this theorem

> Let $G$ and $H$ be finite abelian groups. Then $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic
> if and only if they have the same elementary divisors

The proof in this direction "$\leftarrow$ " is simple. For this "$\rightarrow $", we use strong induction.

[image]

My problem is in the last part, why is it determined in this way that $k = l$?

It happens that I do not understand why $|G|=p^{n_1}\cdots p^{n_r}p^{k-r}$, in particular, what does $p^{k-r}$ mean?

Comment: Images are not searchable, and many screen readers cannot handle them, also making your post inaccessible. It is bad form to rely heavily on them. This is definitely a lot of typing, but you may want to endeavor to include enough content that is searchable and accessible to make your post intelligible.

Comment: What text is it from?

Comment: @Shaun Abstract Algebra An Introductory Course by Gregory T. Lee.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I will try to give the written details, thank you Mr. Arturo

Comment: Note that $n_i = m_i=1$ for all $i >r$, so $p^{n_{r+1}} ... p^{n_k}=p^{k-r}$ and $p^{m_{r+1}} ... p^{n_l}=p^{l-r}$.

Comment: For your second question, it's true by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (FTA).  Call $n$ the order of $G$, then it has a unique factorisation as a product of powers of primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $G$ and $H$ are abelian $p$-groups. We know they have the same order, since they are isomorphic. To clarify the argument, let me modify their notation a bit: we have
$$G = G_1\times\cdots\times G_t\times G_{t+1}\times\cdots\times G_{t+r},$$
where $G_i$ is cyclic of order $p^{n_i}$, $n_i\geq 2$ for $i=1,\ldots,t$, and $G_{t+j}$ is of order $p$ for $j=1,\ldots,r$ (none, if $r=0$), and with $n_1\geq n_2\geq\cdots\geq n_t$. Similarly, let
$$H = H_1\times\cdots\times H_s\times H_{s+1}\times\cdots\times H_{s+v},$$
with similar provisos: $H_i$ is of order $p^{m_i}$ with $m_i\geq 2$ for $i=1,\ldots,s$, and $H_{s+j}$ is of order $p$ for $j=1,\ldots,v$.

The order of $G$ is then $|G|=p^{n_1+\cdots+n_t+r}$ (the last summand of $r$ accounting for the factors of order $p$), and the order of $H$ is $|H|=p^{m_1+\cdots+m_s+v}$.

Now, $G^p$ and $H^p$ have order strictly smaller than $G$ and $H$. Namely, the last $r$ factors "disappear" because they become trivial when we take the $p$th power, and each of the remaining $t$ factors become one power of $p$ smaller. So $|G^p| = p^{(n_1-1)+\cdots+(n_t-1)} = p^{n_1+\cdots+n_t-t}$. Similarly, $|H^p|=p^{(m_1-1)+\cdots+(m_s-1)} = p^{m_1+\cdots+m_s-s}.$

By induction, because the orders of $G^p$ and $H^p$ are strictly smaller, we know that $G^p$ and $H^p$ have the same order and the same elementary divisors. The elementary divisors of $G^p$ are $n_1-1,n_2-1,\ldots,n_t-1$, and those of $H^p$ are $m_1-1,\ldots,m_s-1$. Thus, we conclude that $t=s$ (same number of divisors), and that $m_1=n_1$, $m_2=n_2,\ldots,m_t=n_t$.

To complete the proof, we just need to show that the number of times that $p$ shows up as an elementary divisor for $G$ (namely $r$) is the same as the number of times it shows up for $H$ (namely $v$). But we already know that $m_1=n_1,\ldots,m_t=n_t$, and the order of $G$ is $|G|=p^{n_1+\cdots+n_t+r}$, and the order of $H$ is $p^{m_1+\cdots+m_t+v}$, and that these two are equal (because $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic, so they have the same order). That means that $r=v$ (because $m_1+\cdots+m_t=n_1+\cdots+n_t$). But that is what we needed to show.

Though your quote separates out the case where $t=0$, there is no need: if $t=0$, the argument still  holds, since the induction hypothesis applies then $G$ and $H$ are trivial.

Comment: Your answer has been very instructive Mr. Arturo, thank you very much